# Drools : How to use a variable in the duration specification?

Tags: unit-testing, variables, drools, duration, drools-fusion

I have a set of rules that fire each 15seconds.

As I want to unit-test these rules, I want to set dynamically this duration value.
More, I want to put it in my app's configuration. This value might be used in more than 20 rules...).

How can I do this ? Is it possible ?

Here is my rule :

```
rule "my rule Name"
duration 15000
when
    //match something
then
    //do something
end
```

I would like to have something like :

```
gobal String timeDuration;

rule "my rule Name"
duration timeDuration
when
    //match something
then
    //do something
end
```

I tried : 
- putting a long global variable set from my unit test
- putting a String global variable set from my unit test containing "15s"
- Import a class containing a static field and put

```
import my.temp.package.RemoveThisUglyClass;
rule "my rule Name"
duration RemoveThisUglyClass.timeDuration
when
    //match something
then
    //do something
end
```

Seems that there is no way to do it.
A I right ?
Any suggestion ?

Thanx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `duration` rule attribute is deprecated for quite some time. You can use `timer`:

```
rule "tock"
timer( expr: $d )
when
    A($d: duration )
then
    //...
end
```

This fires after the number of milliseconds in duration, but you can also use String fields containing times like "3s". See the documentation.

Comment: Thanx your response helped me :
I used a global variable containing my duration value and use it directly in the timer.